# Determine if coordinates within Google Map bounds?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have a Google Map already zoomed and positioned. How can I find out if some coordinates are within the map bounds or viewport of the current map? I want to conditionally drop a pin only if the coordinates I feed it is within the current bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[google.maps.LatLngBounds.contains()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

(from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.contains)):

> **contains**
>   contains(latLng)
>   **Parameters:**
>   latLng:  LatLng|LatLngLiteral
>   Return Value:  boolean
>   Returns true if the given lat/lng is in this bounds.